FDC6333C N & P−Channel MOSFETs on waveshare ESP32-S3
I'm stumbled upon the schematic diagram from waveshare ESP32-S3-PICO and doesn't understand much on the so called "Save power" circuit diagram. From the picture, the connection from VUSB and 3V3 into FDC6333C chip, with a N & P mosfet.
Is this a switching circuit used to power the CH343P and CH334F (USB hub)?? If without this FDC6333C circuit, can i just directly hook an external 3.3V power into these CH343P and CH334F? Or this circuit is used to protect from connecting USB and the external power supply together? So that there won't be have two power source into them?
Apologize for my lack of knowledge of electronics and circuitry, am a newbie and still learning :) Cheers!

Full schematic here:
ESP32-S3-Pico-SCH

I edited the link, should be accessible now?

From my understanding it powers the USB modules only when the USB cable is connected, so VBUS is 5V.
But I'm not sure, that schematic (https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/a/a7/ESP32-S3-Pico-SCH.pdf) is pretty hard to follow. You have to hunt the labels all over the page.

Yeah, I'm not sure too. It looks like when USB is connected, it then only draw the power from the USB to supply the USB module and the USB hub.
